# using jquery ajax to update/delete a given db row via a website link

Tags: jquery, ajax

I hope somebody out there will take a few minutes of their day/life to document how to do this for myself and others.

I am wanting to have a jquery ajax method that will update/delete a given row in a database table. I know how to do the php/sql end, I am just not skilled at all with jquery ajax.

So for example, I have the following html code:

```
<div id="s1">
Something #1
<a href="#" class="check" id="s1">process</a>
</div>
<div id="s2">
Something #2
<a href="#" class="check" id="s2">process</a>
</div>
<div id="s3">
Something #3
<a href="#" class="check" id="s3">process</a>
</div>
```

What would be the jQuery.post() javascript code that would be used to pull the id value of the specific link and push it through to the .php file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -

```
$("a").click(function() {
   $.post('delete.php',{ id: $(this).attr("id")});
});
```

That should post the 'id' of the element you clicked to the 'delete.php' page within the 'id' form variable.